# Filtering AddressList by MailGroup that is only a certain domain in Multi-Domain tenant

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

client has 2 different domains (due to acquisition) in one M365 tenant and wants to make sure they don't see each other in contacts using Address Book Policies. I have been able to do my best to separate them by using Company field however I am stuck with how to handle their Mail-Enabled Security Groups.

I made an address list called "Client1AddressList" and set the -IncludedRecipients to "MailGroups" which is great and brings every group in, however it doesn't care about the domain whether it is allstaff@client1.com or allstaff@client2.com.

I thought maybe adding on a -RecipientFilter to the end of the Set-AddressList would help, but I cant figure out what that filter would look like to tell it to only add groups that have an email of *@client1.com

Thank you any geniuses out there that can lend a hand!

Comment: You don't show any code, but I can imaging filtering with a piped `Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -like '*@client1.com'}` should do it (provided the property name is indeed `EmailAddress`)

Comment: You are right sorry, I am new to using this (stack overflow) - should have included that. 

It would be something like this? 

`Set-AddressList -Identity "Company1Groups" -IncludedRecipients MailGroups -RecipientFilter *I Dont Know What To Put Here*`

I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @Theo that is also a good point about the EmailAddress property. I have been trying to figure out where to find the definitive property name of the groups email address assigned to it, but don't know where to look.

Comment: @Theo I tried this:

`Set-AddressList -Identity "Company1Group" -IncludedRecipients MailGroups | Where-Object {$_.EmailAddress -like '*@company1.ca'}`

This was the output:

`WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of '\Company1Group' have been modified.`

I checked and it still shows company2 groups in the address list.